# Replacement of the line after pattern using external file with pattern mapping

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I am looking for shell script that will replace in the file couple of thousand lines after lines consisting of constant pattern and variable patern. The patterns mapping is in external file.

Source/target file **abc.txt** has got such shape:

```
something not to be changed
123: aaa
bla bla

something else
123: abc
bla bla

And something more
123: ccc
bla bla
```

pattern mapping file **pat.txt** has got such shape:

```
abc pattern     xyz
aaa pattern     xxx
ccc pattern     zzz
```

Now I need to change the line

```
bla bla
```

to proper pattern i.e. line after 123: abc should be changed to xyz

I have clue on specific steps like:
Changing the line after matching pattern

```
sed '/abc/!b;n;c/xyz' abc.txt
```

or displaing lines before pattern:

```
grep -B1 "bla bla" abc.txt
```

or displaying lines after mathing pattern:

```
grep -A1 "123" abc.txt
```

or returning rest of the pattern mapping from pat.txt

```
grep "abc" pat.txt | sed -n -e 's/^.*pattern  //p'
```

but I have no clue how to make it together.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to change an entire line to a fixed string, I prefer `s` to `c`, like this:

```
/abc/{n;s/.*/xyz/;}
```

just because `c` is so fussy about newlines (at least in my version of sed). Use `c` if you prefer it.

So here is the sed script we need:

```
/^123: abc$/{n;s/.*/xyz/;}
/^123: aaa$/{n;s/.*/xxx/;}
/^123: ccc$/{n;s/.*/zzz/;}
```

My approach would be to convert your **pat.txt** into that script, by means of another sed command:

```
sed 's|^\([^ ]*\) pattern *\(.*\)$|/^123: \1$/{n;s/.*/\2/;}|' pat.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds like good approach. So the script will run many times sed command changing single pattern in the abc.txt file. I guess then I need to add sed command and  abc.txt  into each command as well?

Comment: So i created two scripts translate-1step.sh:
`cat pat.txt | sed -e 's/^\([^ ]*\) pattern *\(.*\)$/sed -i \x27\/123: \1\/!b;n;c \2 \x27 abc.txt/' > translate-2step.sh`
which creates translate2step.sh based on pat.txt in this example it is:
`sed -i '/123: abc/!b;n;c xyz ' abc.txt
sed -i '/123: aaa/!b;n;c xxx ' abc.txt
sed -i '/123: ccc/!b;n;c zzz ' abc.txt`
which seems to do the job. Thanks for the idea how to solve it!

Comment: @Marcin: You seem to be working harder that you must. Here is what I suggest: **Step 1:**  `sed 's|^\([^ ]*\) pattern *\(.*\)$|/^123: \1$/{n;s/.*/\2/;}|' pat.txt > script.sed` **Step 2:** `sed -f script.sed  abc.txt > xyz.txt`